# How to replace or block Windows Taskbar and Desktop for security reasons, programatically?

Tags: windows, delphi, desktop

Like some cyber coffee applications that disables the user ability to use any other application but only the ones started inside that cyber admin application panel, I searched the Internet for some way of doing it in Delphi:

- Remove the Windows Task bar;
- Disable the Alt+Tab function;
- Disable the Task Manager;
- Be able to do/undo that changes in a configuration panel.

These needs are for keeping users from downloading viruses and making changes to Windows configuration or even play games, if it is the system administrator's preference. *The own program would serve as a container for authorized applications to run inside then as if it were a MDI application. That is already working*

Of course that the system manager will have the options to disable that or revert.

Is there a way to make those four configurations in run-time with **Delphi XE3**?

Comment: Can't all those be controlled through group policy?

Comment: Sounds like a Stack exchange question, and would probably get more attention over there.

Comment: @Ampt Uh...Stack Exchange is the name of the whole QnA network.

Comment: @Ampt Probably means StackOverflow.

Comment: Be aware that doing these things programmaticly is likely to make your software trigger any antivirus protection on the computer. Those are all things a virus may do to hide itself.

Comment: @Katana314 Whooops, you caught me!

Comment: What you are looking for is whats often referred to as 'Kiosk' mode.  You should find a lot of information if you search on that term.

Comment: Uninstall the games and change the security settings so the user can't install any software.

Comment: You need to look into **kiosk mode**, GPO, and probably something like Deep Freeze or running everything as a VM from a known clean (and unchangeable) master image. If I walked into your cybercafe & saw that only your custom applications could be used, I would not touch the computers as I would immediately be suspicious of main-in-the-middle attacks, keyloggers, and overall tracking/logging every last thing I did - major security concern for me as a user.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about system setup rather than the design or concepts of programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Delphi.  I'm also not sure if it is possible during run-time. But you could do the following:

1. Write to the registry to prevent alt-tab [see this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/96925/).
2. Again write to the registry to disable Task Manager [see this](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/163/).
3. Sounds like you can disable the task bar too by the registry [see this](http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/159/).
4. On your control panel have options and when they hit save, save and restart the computer.

This is provided that Delphi can write to the registry (I believe C# and C++ can).  If not, you could create .reg files and execute those by calling cmd.exe with arguments.  This I think will cause some pop-ups though.

**Update:** You may be able to load in the registry changes without a signing out by killing explorer.exe and then loading it again.  This may only load parts of the updated registry though.

Comment: Besides, they're one-time changes, so you can put them in a .reg file and apply that. No programming needed.

Comment: This is roughly what we've done for our in vehicle tablet systems.  If the drivers can get access to any of the Windows components they will use it to play games while they drive. We included the registry changes in the installer.  It's worked really well for us.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest booting your hardware into Linux, and then run a Windows virtual machine that is as locked down as possible using the existing kiosk mode security settings in Windows.  This VM then runs your MDI application when the VM boots.  When the MDI application exists the VM reverts to a snapshot of the known good Windows configuration.

You strip down a Linux OS to include only the bare minimum components needed to host your Windows VM.

I'm assuming your MDI windows will only host applications your organization has written, not arbitrary Windows executables.  Otherwise you are asking to re-write Windows itself, which will prove impossible.